# Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, string, exception

I'm new to Java programming for Android. This is the first language I use to develop apps. The problem I have on my app is:

It has 4 text fields (editText) and two buttons (Button).
The app gets data from editText, convert it to string than converts it to double to calculate the results. The problem is, when I press the "Calculate" button, and if at least one text field is empty, the app crashes.

===============================================

Here is the LogCat:

```
05-29 19:00:13.885: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 750 objects / 55088 bytes in 60ms
05-29 19:10:26.747: D/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
05-29 19:10:26.747: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at mais.vantagem.yep.MaisVantagemActivity.onClick(MaisVantagemActivity.java:93)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-29 19:10:26.774: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

===============================================

=====================

SOLUTION:

just solved this using `StringName.equals("")` for all the instances.

As you can see:

```
if(quantidadeAString.equals("") || quantidadeBString.equals("") || valorAString.equals("") || valorBString.equals("")){
                    resultado.setText("Valores Inválidos");
                }

                else {
                double qtdANum = Double.parseDouble(quantidadeAString);
                double qtdBNum = Double.parseDouble(quantidadeBString);
                double valorANum = Double.parseDouble(valorAString);
                double valorBNum = Double.parseDouble(valorBString);
}
```

Thank you all for the help and ideas to get it to work. Many Thanks!

Soon I'll be here with more questions.

Comment: So you're trying to convert an empty `String` into a `double`. The solution is not to let that happen. Please post code

Comment: Just posted the code. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should check if there is one text field is empty or null before you try to calculate/parse from String to number.

Simple as that :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a non floating string to float. Try using try{} catch{} blocks to catch the exception and prevent crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass an empty string to parseDouble. This throws, as explained in the error a "NumberFormatException" because the parser cannot make sense of it.

You need to surround your call to parseDouble in a try catch block:

```
void yourMethod() {
    String s = ... get string from text field ...

    double d;
    try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Something went wrong...
    }
}
```

If "something went wrong" you can abandon your calculations or somehow notify the user that they need to pass a value, etc.

This solution also prevents the user from putting non-numeric garbage in the text fields, such as letters and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if edittext is null or empty before Calculation and use try/catch as:

```
edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dttxt);
    if ((edittext.getText().toString().trim().getLength() == 0) && ("").equals(edittext.getText().toString().trim())){

    try{

        //Calculate here

        }catch(NumberFormatException ex)
       {
       }
}
```